# How to use curl to confirm user scope access?

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, http-post, spring-security-oauth2

I configured an authorization server and I can send it the following request:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1pdHRpcHJvdmVuY2VAeWFob28uc2UiLCJmdWxsbmFtZSI6IlN0ZXBoYW5lIEV5YmVydCIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwic3ViIjoibWl0dGlwcm92ZW5jZUB5YWhvby5zZSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly90aGFsYXNvZnQuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQxNTExMDg0LCJleHAiOjE1NDE1MTQ2ODR9.90fZX0wjd0YH4ooosjBNvzmYM3tsusULl5GyBYy8B9wEexW_tu2yBS8ZEIbotwqDUryZkPxXFt5qqJvOjiVVAQ" "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/authorize?client_id=ng-zero&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fcallback&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424&response_type=code&scope=read_profile" -X POST 
HTTP/1.1 200 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1E87C912487850BE2DE6C71343C35E6E; Path=/api; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-store
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 571
Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2018 14:20:15 GMT

<html><body><h1>OAuth Approval</h1><p>Do you authorize "ng-zero" to access your protected resources?</p><form id="confirmationForm" name="confirmationForm" action="/api/oauth/authorize" method="post"><input name="user_oauth_approval" value="true" type="hidden"/><label><input name="authorize" value="Authorize" type="submit"/></label></form><form id="denialForm" name="denialForm" action="/api/oauth/authorize" method="post"><input name="user_oauth_approval" value="false" type="hidden"/><label><input name="deny" value="Deny" type="submit"/></label></form></body></html>
```

Now I would like to validate that form, that is, pseudo click on its `Authorize` button.

From this, I expect to receive a response that is a redirect to the callback url.

I tried giving it the `user_oauth_approval` form parameter but it didn't help:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1pdHRpcHJvdmVuY2VAeWFob28uc2UiLCJmdWxsbmFtZSI6IlN0ZXBoYW5lIEV5YmVydCIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwic3ViIjoibWl0dGlwcm92ZW5jZUB5YWhvby5zZSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly90aGFsYXNvZnQuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQxNTExMDg0LCJleHAiOjE1NDE1MTQ2ODR9.90fZX0wjd0YH4ooosjBNvzmYM3tsusULl5GyBYy8B9wEexW_tu2yBS8ZEIbotwqDUryZkPxXFt5qqJvOjiVVAQ" "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/authorize?client_id=ng-zero&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fcallback&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424&response_type=code&scope=read_profile" -X POST -d "{ \"user_oauth_approval\" : \"true\" }"HTTP/1.1 200 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=BDB2B137C9A6E10B3E802A8AF9E705C8; Path=/api; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-store
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 571
Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2018 14:15:59 GMT

<html><body><h1>OAuth Approval</h1><p>Do you authorize "ng-zero" to access your protected resources?</p><form id="confirmationForm" name="confirmationForm" action="/api/oauth/authorize" method="post"><input name="user_oauth_approval" value="true" type="hidden"/><label><input name="authorize" value="Authorize" type="submit"/></label></form><form id="denialForm" name="denialForm" action="/api/oauth/authorize" method="post"><input name="user_oauth_approval" value="false" type="hidden"/><label><input name="deny" value="Deny" type="submit"/></label></form></body></html>[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X201 user-rest (master)]
```

I tried passing it the `JSESSIONID` cookie but it didn't help either:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1pdHRpcHJvdmVuY2VAeWFob28uc2UiLCJmdWxsbmFtZSI6IlN0ZXBoYW5lIEV5YmVydCIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwic3ViIjoibWl0dGlwcm92ZW5jZUB5YWhvby5zZSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly90aGFsYXNvZnQuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQxNTE5OTU5LCJleHAiOjE1NDE1MjM1NTl9.vcUtEhLDLF5vpeMofwQ9k2rKgZzo52l2nuCN7GZ04D4ZCMXpckS5mwEoROZ5CqucjoTJEDHg-CwSDH4HcM0Xtw" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=D7A7AE9A76C46AA49FA928979BEB5FF6" "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/authorize?client_id=ng-zero&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fcallback&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424&response_type=code&scope=read_profile" -X POST -d "{ \"user_oauth_approval\" : \"true\" }"
HTTP/1.1 200 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=43D30521A2C3F8EF66D0F5B655DEFAF5; Path=/api; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-store
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 571
Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2018 16:01:21 GMT

<html><body><h1>OAuth Approval</h1><p>Do you authorize "ng-zero" to access your protected resources?</p><form id="confirmationForm" name="confirmationForm" action="/api/oauth/authorize" method="post"><input name="user_oauth_approval" value="true" type="hidden"/><label><input name="authorize" value="Authorize" type="submit"/></label></form><form id="denialForm" name="denialForm" action="/api/oauth/authorize" method="post"><input name="user_oauth_approval" value="false" type="hidden"/><label><input name="deny" value="Deny" type="submit"/></label></form></body></html>
```

I also tried adding the submit element data:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1pdHRpcHJvdmVuY2VAeWFob28uc2UiLCJmdWxsbmFtZSI6IlN0ZXBoYW5lIEV5YmVydCIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwic3ViIjoibWl0dGlwcm92ZW5jZUB5YWhvby5zZSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly90aGFsYXNvZnQuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQxNTE5OTU5LCJleHAiOjE1NDE1MjM1NTl9.vcUtEhLDLF5vpeMofwQ9k2rKgZzo52l2nuCN7GZ04D4ZCMXpckS5mwEoROZ5CqucjoTJEDHg-CwSDH4HcM0Xtw" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=D7A7AE9A76C46AA49FA928979BEB5FF6" "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/authorize?client_id=ng-zero&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fcallback&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424&response_type=code&scope=read_profile" -X POST -d "{ \"user_oauth_approval\" : \"true\", \"authorize\" : \"Authorize\" }"
```

but it's still the same response.

I've also tried with httpie using the request:

```
$ http -f POST http://localhost:8080/api/auth/authorize client_id=="ng-zero" redirect_uri=="http://localhost:4200/callback" state=="DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424" response_type=="code" scope=="read_profile" "Accept:application/json" "Content-Type:application/json" "Authorization:Bearer $TOKEN" "Cookie:JSESSIONID=8D6D0C673961FB6DDB5F94DB1AC93EC7; Path=/api; HttpOnly" user_oauth_approval="true" authorize="Authorize"
HTTP/1.1 200 
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 571
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2018 13:53:23 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5CB863D4C5F594E05D9E0C5422DE3B9A; Path=/api; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

<html><body><h1>OAuth Approval</h1><p>Do you authorize "ng-zero" to access your protected resources?</p><form id="confirmationForm" name="confirmationForm" action="/api/oauth/authorize" method="post"><input name="user_oauth_approval" value="true" type="hidden"/><label><input name="authorize" value="Authorize" type="submit"/></label></form><form id="denialForm" name="denialForm" action="/api/oauth/authorize" method="post"><input name="user_oauth_approval" value="false" type="hidden"/><label><input name="deny" value="Deny" type="submit"/></label></form></body></html>
```

but it is the same issue.

Providing the `JSESSIONID` value of the previous request does not submit the form but displays it again.

How can I submit this form using `curl` again ?

Comment: Why do you use cURL? Use a browser. However, you have to add the session cookie and send the form input with right content type. If you use a browser, you could see, how the request should look (headers, cookies, body).

Comment: Say I do this with Chrome, how do I pass in the headers then ?

Comment: You hav nothing to do, it should work by default. Just enter the URL.

Comment: In order not to be 401ed I need to pass in the request asking for the form, a bearer access token, this in a header...

Comment: No, you only need to call the protected resource, then you are redirected to login page.

Comment: I'm implementing my own OAuth2 provider here. Do I have to have a redirection ? Can't I have a stateless auth server and return a 401 if not logged in ?